# why the function address that gdb shows is different with that of nm?

Tags: linux

Today, when I debug my code on linux, I suddenly find that the function address in **gdb** is different with what **nm** shows. (The executable is statically linked.)

I thought that the addresses that they show should have been the same, as they were all logical addresses. But today's finding makes me confused.

Does someone know the reason why they are different?

I write the following simple program to illustrate what I encountered.

```
void fo()              
{                      
    return ;           
}                      


void foo()             
{                      
    fo();              
}                      

int add(int a, int b)  
{                      
    foo();             
    return  a + b;     
}                      

int main()             
{                      
    int a = 1;         
    int b = 2;         
    add(a, b);         

    return 0;          
}
```

the output of **nm** is:

```
0000000000400584 T _Z2fov
0000000000400595 T _Z3addii
000000000040058a T _Z3foov
00000000004005b3 T main
```

but when I use gdb to debug the compiled executable, putting the breakpoint at line 3.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  fo () at test.cpp:4
#1  0x0000000000400593 in foo () at test.cpp:9
#2  0x00000000004005a8 in add (a=1, b=2) at test.cpp:14
#3  0x00000000004005d8 in main () at test.cpp:22
```

you can see that the **output of gdb** is different from that of **nm**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `nm` shows the address of the *start* of the function, while `gdb` *stacktrace* shows where exactly the execution has progressed *inside* the function. Precisely it should be the return address in the stack frame, that is pointer to next instruction to be executed in the function when the function above it in stack returns.

Note, that if you just ask `gdb` for the function pointer by evaluating function pointer expression, it should give the same address as `nm`.

Comment: Unless the binary has been relocated on loading, etc, etc, so on and so forth.

Comment: @Vatine, could you say more on that? can binary relocation affect the symbol address?

Comment: when does binary relocation happen?